# Distinguish a code comment from a text comment

Tags: javascript, validation, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there an optimal way to see if a single line or block comment is merely code that was commented out, or if it is an actual comment.

e.g.

```
// console.log('foo');
```

> Should validate `true` of being a code comment.

```
// This does stuff
```

> Should validate `false` of being a code comment.

#### Current Solution:

Parse the comment contents through to an AST and see if it's code or not, kind of like a validator.

#### Assumptions:

- I have access to the original code parsed into an AST already and have access to a comment node.
- Is going to be a node script.

Comment: How would you parse this, `// obsolete (remove);`

Comment: Also, how would you distinguish human language from syntactically invalid code (that's why it was commented out)?

Comment: I'd say, this is at least very close to unsolvable.

Comment: Surely you'd be able to go that `// obsolete (remove);` isn't valid code, because it wouldn't make sense in the context of the rest of the code... It just doesn't sit right with me that no one has ever in the existence of computer science been able to figure out a way to find this distinguishment.

Comment: There is no distinction. Whatever follows  `// ` is an actual comment.   `// function(){window.alert("This is a function");} ` is no more a _code comment_, than  `var x = 'function(){window.alert("This is a function");}';` is a _code string_. The former is a comment, the latter is a string. Neither of them are code.

Comment: But you take away the quotes and you get a `function`, or you take away the `//` and you get a `function`. @Rounin

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But as soon as you add the `//` all you have is a comment - it doesn't matter what the alphanumeric content of that comment is - it's just a comment.

Comment: Maybe I did a poor job of articulating what I'm asking, but that is the whole point. I wanting through static analysis to figure out if that comment contains code, or contains text. @Rounin

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect the comment text, and run it through a language substring recognizer.  You might have:

```
 /*  X=2.7*Y^3+9.3^Y2+2.7*  */
```

That looks like code to me, even if it is incomplete.

So in general you want to detect substrings of the language as opposed to arbitrarily chosen language structures.  (Even if you choose expansion of langauge just nonterminals as defined by a grammar, do you include all 1000 of the nonterminals in your complex grammar? Just "statement" or "expression"?

Your first problem will be deciding where the "comment" begins or ends. Is

```
 //  X=X+1;
 /*  foo(bar);
     bar(baz);
 */
```

one code block or two (or three)?  What if the apparant code is split across comments?

```
//  X=X+
/*  1;  */
```

I'd guess your biggest problem is finding a langauge substring parser.  Just because you have a parser for the full language doesn't mean you an easily build a subtring recognizer with it.  (We have done that by bending GLR parsers for our tools, see my bio if you want to know more).

Your hardest problem is intention:  did the programmer really comment out actual code, or was she just sketching a computation in a comment? You can't know unless you can read long-gone minds.